# Nested Loops Asymptotic analysis

Tags: algorithm, loops, big-o, time-complexity

Need help figuring this hw example out guys.
the example states 0(n) running time.
I see that the outter loop is O(logn)
I cant figure out how to describe the inner loop in relation to n.
Help is much appreciated.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i = i*2) // log n 
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)  // less than n i don't know how to describe the growth
        sum++;
```

Answer:: 0(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easiest to analyze the runtime of the piece of code in the aggregate. On the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will run 1 time. On the second iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will run 2 times. On the third iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will run 4 times. More generally, on the kth iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will run 2<sup>k</sup> times. The outer loop stops as soon as i becomes greater than N, which happens after log<sub>2</sub> N iterations.

If we sum up the total work done, we'll see that it's

> 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2<sup>log<sub>2</sub> N</sup> = 2<sup>log<sub>2</sub> N + 1</sup> - 1 = 2n - 1

(This uses the fact that 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2<sup>k</sup> = 2<sup>k+1</sup> - 1). Therefore, the total work done for the entire piece of code (that is, including both loops) is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is O(n) time because it will go through each element once. If i is 1000, 1000 times, if i is 10000, 10000 times, etc.

Comment: A better bound for the inner loop would be O(i) rather than O(n), since the runtime depends on the value of i rather than the value of n.

Comment: isnt it a fraction of n? since 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + N ~ 2N times.

Comment: @templatetypedef yea that was my problem i could not express it in terms of n,i came up with o(i) as well